# Canvas drawimage() not displaying image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to make a full screen, responsive image on Canvas. I believe I have the sizing figured out, but it isn't drawing the image and is instead leaving the canvas blank.

This is the HTML and JavaScript I am currently using:

```
<canvas id="MainCanvas"></canvas>
<script> 
    var canvas = document.getElementById("MainCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    var wRatio = canvas.width / imageObj.width;
    var hRatio = canvas.height / imageObj.height;
    var ratio = Math.min (wRatio, hRatio);
    var imageObj = new Image();  
    imageObj.onload= function() {
     context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height,imageObj.width*ratio, imageObj.height*ratio);
    };
    imageObj.src="Local File.jpg";
</script>
```

CSS:

```
canvas{
   border: 5pt solid black;
   position: relative;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, good job on the minimal example.  When I ran it in jsFiddle, here's what I got in my javascript console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined
```

Looking at your code, i noticed that it was trying to reference the width and height of the image before it had loaded.  I put that code inside your `onLoad` function and that error was corrected.  Next I got this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': Valid arities are: [3, 5, 9], but 7 arguments provided.
```

Seeing that, I looked up [`CanvasRenderingContext2D` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage).  That showed me what it required, and I added a `0,0` for the `dx, dy` values.  This is completely wrong of course, but it at least gets the image to render ([jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/sjb3fcwr/) if the below example doesn't work correctly):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("MainCanvas");
console.log(canvas);
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var imageObj = new Image();  
imageObj.onload= function() {
    var wRatio = canvas.width / imageObj.width;
    var hRatio = canvas.height / imageObj.height;
    var ratio = Math.min (wRatio, hRatio);
    context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height,0,0,imageObj.width*ratio, imageObj.height*ratio);
};
imageObj.src="//placehold.it/500";
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

canvas{
    border: 5pt solid black;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<canvas id="MainCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you!  Using  `context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height) ` and `object-fit: cover; ` in CSS have my image showing and sizing correctly.
I'm not sure how removing `imageObj.height*ratio` and `imageObj.width*ratio` will affect it, but it seems to be working for now.

Comment: @Dragoris, avoid using css to set the width height and object-fit of a canvas, this will only stretch things...

Comment: @Kaiido Ok, that's good to know. Thank you. Do you have a suggested way to size the canvas and image more effectively?